# crash when hit rate us button and back to app

Tags: objective-c

i have a rate us button in our app .
when you hit it, i got :

```
    [player stop];
    [player release];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appName/idnumber?ls=1&mt=8"]];
```

it takes me to the app page in the app store, but then if i open the app again from the home button on the device, (back to the app), if then i hit any other button to start playing again, i got crash and:

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CAContextImpl stop]:
```

i dont know even where to search..
any help ?

Comment: got it ! it happens because i stop the music before i go out to the url. i have to not stop the music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest starting with Instruments and its template for checking zombies.  I assume that `player` isn't supposed to be a `CAContextImpl` object in your code but that's what the variable is pointing to at the time of the error.

That suggests that your player has already been released and the memory management system has re-used that piece of memory.

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to make it work but you might want to use the Product->Analyze menu to see if there's still something odd there.